# How to make notifications for a chat on an Android application with a PHP application server?

Tags: php, android, xmpp, google-cloud-messaging

I am designing a commercial application which needs a chat as a feature.
I currently use PHP / MySQL for my application server.
I have been doing some research and I found answers that raised new questions.

Here are the different possibilities I found that seemed interesting for implementing upstream and downstream communications:

1. GCM using XMPP for persistent connection and upstream notifications but since PHP is inherently synchronous, I doubt it is reliable for a scalable application. I found this as a possible solution using a modified version of JAXL: http://doublenegative.com/tag/xmpp/
2. GCM with HTTP for downstream notifications. Classic ASyncTask with an HTTP connection for upstream.
3. Implement a second application server in a language different from PHP (JSP, ruby, django) for handling GCM via XMPP.

I really do not know what to choose between those 3 points because I don't know to find out that the first solution is not reliable if there are a few users. In the meantime, I have deadlines and it would hinder me to use a different technology I am less familiar with for the application server.

Thank you for your replies !

Samuel